# how to display matching set of values in combobox when text is entered in combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am using combobox (c# windows forms) to display the set of matching values from database on combobox, when user enters some  text in combobox. I am not getting exact idea to write the code.

Any help is really appreciated..

Comment: do you mean that you want an autocomplete function on the combo box ?

Comment: yes i mean to say when i enter text letters like "ab" in combobox it should display the related values like abaccus abbis absent in a list .

Answer (score 2):

A ComboBox already has an autocomplete feature. Have a look at these properties on MSDN:

[AutocompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx) and [AutocompleteSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletesource.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to pay [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/dropdown-and-list.aspx#autocomplete-modes) has some controls with this functionality built-in

EDIT: it seems that the normal combo box also supports [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/cf62ab00-1513-472a-b3ac-3e77fe36028c/) also shows a quick example